# Apex errors preventing DX code push to scratch org

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I've inherited a large project with lots of Apex code. I'm trying to use Salesforce DX to push code to a scratch org via `sfdx force:source:push`, so I can run tests. When I do this, I get a whole mess of errors about missing variables and so on. These errors have existed in the code for a long time without problems, and I don't want to modify a bunch of legacy code just to get started on unrelated features. Is there a way to tell DX to push the code to the scratch org regardless of errors?

I believe the reason the errors aren't currently an issue is that the various Apex classes are keyed to various API versions, and the problems aren't errors in those API versions.

Comment: It has to compile. If you are getting compile failures, you have to fix them. That likely means you missed dependencies and need to go into your package to include them.

Comment: Addendum: if you use managed packages in your org, you need to install those in the scratch org. I've found that having a directory (I called mine `packages`) that just contains a package.xml and the necessary installedPackages metadata files is easy enough to push with `force:mdapi:deploy`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you converted your Apex code to the Salesforce DX format, but if it was from something like a Mavensmate project, the project manifest (package.xml) does not (generally) include the Custom Field and Custom Object metadata types, which would explain why you get errors related to references in your Apex code. At a minimum you will need to retrieve and convert (to Salesforce DX format) all of the custom object/fields referenced by the Apex code and push them to the scratch org as well.